# How to separate different parts with exit control in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I am writing a complicated Makefile which have multiple parts like:

```
step1:
    if [[ ${input} == "delete" ]]; then          \
        echo "this is a test to delete files";   \
    else                                         \
        echo "error stop";                       \
    fi

step2:
    rm -f *.txt

test:
    make step1
    make step2
```

So if I enter "make test input=delete", it will delete all the .txt files. And if I enter "make test input=none", it would not do anything. I know the simplest way is to combine step1 and step2 as:

```
test:
    if [[ ${input} == "delete" ]]; then          \
        echo "this is a test to delete files";   \
        rm -f *.txt;                             \
    else                                         \
        echo "error stop";                       \
    fi
```

But my Makefile is so complicated that I have to separate into several parts. Does Makefile support similar features? If yes, what should I look for? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using GNU Make? If so you could use its `ifeq`.

Comment: Yes. I am using GNU Make. Can you give some more info about how to use `ifeq` to achieve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should always use `$(MAKE)` and never use `make` directly when invoking a sub-make.

If you do that, then all command-line overrides you provide will be correctly passed to the sub-makes.

BTW, you should not use the bash syntax `[[ x == y ]]`.  If you run this makefile on a system where the default shell is limited to POSIX standard syntax this won't work.  You should use POSIX syntax: `[ x = y ]`.

Comment: I see. Thanks. How does this help in this case? If what I understand correctly, if I use `make test input=delete`, then step1 would print out _error stop_, but step2 would still be executed. Is that correct?

Comment: If you want step2 to not run you can change your `echo "error stop"` to `exit 1` so that `step1` gives an error, then the rest of the lines in `test` will not be invoked after the `$(MAKE) step1` fails.

Answer (score -1):

As you use GNU Make you can use its conditionals, e.g.
[`ifeq`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-ifeq):

```makefile
test:
ifeq ($(input),delete)
    echo "this is a test to delete files"
    rm -f *.txt
else
    echo "error stop"
endif
```

Or, if you want to control the prerequisites of a target:

```makefile
step1:
    echo "this is a test to delete files"

step2:
    rm -f *.txt

# test always depends on step1
test: step1

# test also depends on step2, if input = delete
ifeq ($(input),delete)
test: step2
endif
```